# Как сделать отступ при скролле на определенное количество пикселей?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как при скролле сделать отступ от верха экрана на определенное число пикселей? Благодарю!

```js
$('html,body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('.tabs_container').offset().top + "px"
}, {
  duration: 1E3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `- [нужное_кол-во]px`? ))))

Comment: `$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.tabs_container').offset().top - 100 });`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
  if (offset > 0) {
    $('селектор елемента').css('padding', '10px');
  } else {
    $('селектор елемента').css('padding', '0px');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```